# Problem with Google SOAP API URL

Tags: php, html

I have a doubt with Google API URL. Currently I am doing search engine with google clone serach engine PHP scripts. In this search engine AdSense is working good. But in the SEO box if I give any key words in this sense there is no changes. I got a API Soap key.

```
$soapclient = new soapclient("http://api.google.com/search/beta2");
  $result = $soapclient->call("doGoogleSearch", $parameters, "urn:GoogleSearch");
  $begin = $start + 1;
  $end = $start + $parameters["maxResults"];
  $total = $result["estimatedTotalResultsCount"];
```

I checked with that `$soapclient` http://api.google.com/search/beta2. When I go that url it displays  PAGE NOT FOUND.

Where can I get the current google Soap client url. I dont know either my problem is with that URL or not.

If any one knows about it please tell me.

Comment: You cannot browse it from browser. It does not respond to GET request and gives out 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOAP Search API was deprecated in 2006 and closed in 2009.

The current recommendation is to use the [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).