# multiple errors when i try to run a google api library in the processing environment

Tags: api, search, processing

i get the following errors when i try to run a google search api for processing. so it is a api made for the codeing enviroment processing.  This is the error:

```
earchBy: Processing
com.google.soap.search.GoogleSearchFault: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Protocol; msg=Unsupported response content type "text/html; charset=UTF-8", must be: "text/xml". Response was:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,width=device-width">
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
make event
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
</style>
<a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
<p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
<p>The requested URL <code>/search/beta2</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
]
at com.google.soap.search.GoogleSearch.doSearch(GoogleSearch.java:197)
at saito.google.Google.doQuery(Google.java:93)
at saito.google.Google.run(Google.java:76)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Disabling googleEvent() because of an error.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at saito.google.Google.makeEvent(Google.java:163)
at saito.google.Google.run(Google.java:78)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at google_api_test.googleEvent(google_api_test.java:82)
... 7 more
```

and this is the my code:

```java
import saito.google.*;
String WORD = "Processing";
Google google;

void setup(){
size(200, 200);


google = new Google(this, "here is my api key");
google.searchBy(WORD);

smooth();
}

void draw(){
   background(255);

   if( google.isSearching() ){

   }
}
void mousePressed(){
    google.gotoNext();
}
void googleEvent(GoogleResult result){
    println("total: " + result.totalResultsCount());
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
        println(result.title(i) + " : "+ result.url(i) + "-" + enter code hereresult.summary(i));
    }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Where are you getting the google api library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a [very old library](http://users.design.ucla.edu/~tatsuyas/tools/googld.back/), whose last release was almost 11 years ago.

That library uses the Google SOAP API, which was [deprecated in 2006 and disabled in 2009](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/08/well-earned-retirement-for-soap-search.html).

In other words, that library won't work anymore.

Google has [a new search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1) that you should be using instead. [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1) is a link to a Java wrapper of that API.

See also: [Problem with Google SOAP API URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851099/problem-with-google-soap-api-url)

Comment: how can i make it that this work with processing? i am not very familiar with processing and google api's

Comment: @FutureCake Google has [a new search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1) that you should be using instead. [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1) is a link to a Java wrapper of that API. Try something and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.